# Boost::asio sockets - how to disconnect them cleanly?

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio

I am using boost asynchronous sockets for my server application. I've created a disconnect() function that calls boost's close() and then deletes the socket (operator delete).
 And it's alright when the function is called from one of the async. handlers, but when I call it from inside my main codebase, the whole application crashes at one of the async handlers. 
 How to close a socket nicely in boost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Make sure** that the object is alive as long as handlers that may use it exist.

It is likely what one of handlers that uses this socket is called after you call close (as it
reports the error to handler) and then accesses to dead pointer...

Usually, life time handling can be easily done with `boost::shared_ptr` and `boost::enable_shared_from_this` and passing it in handlers. See numerous examples provided with Boost.Asio.

Once you get familiar with this technique the question you asked would look trivial for you.

Comment: I would prefer not to use smart pointers, as raw pointers are more native for me.

Comment: @vladimir, just because you feel something is more native, does not make it good practice.  Smart pointers solve a lot of problems that otherwise can be a ballache :)

Answer (score 1):

You do want to look into the shutdown method on a socket as well. It will not solve your crashing application. Artyom above already explained the cause of that, but it is interesting nonetheless.
If you close a socket without calling shutdown it might result in a RST being send instead of a gracefull FIN handshake.